# Cant get the right outcome with strtok() , need help , c

Tags: c, strtok

Am working on a project where it is a communication between server client. Server opens a specific file and stores the message from the client in a buffer using  while(1) for repeated communication. All am trying is manage the message like, when client sends this message : AT+REG1=5 , i want to split it ("=") in order to  determine operations and values : operation = AT+REG1 And value is 5. In my code i have a struct with informations  for "operation" and "value". I use **strtok** function to split message but it doesnt work right  and i dont know why , for example i send through client AT+REG1=5  and when i split the message like :

```
token=strtok("AT+REG1=5","="); // points to AT+REG1
value=strtok(NULL,"="); // points to the value but returns null
```

It returns that value is (null) despite that it must return "5".
My build for that is :

```
typedef enum operation{
    insert,
    read_reg,
    info
}Operation;
typedef struct request{
    Operation operation;
    int ID;
    int **regs;
}Request;
```

Function that handles the split of message:

```
Request *parse_request(char *buffer){

    char *token=NULL,*value=NULL;
    Request *rep=NULL;
    
    rep=(Request*)malloc(sizeof(Request));
    

    token=strtok(buffer,"=");
    printf("token:%s\n",token);
    value=strtok(NULL," ");
    printf("value=%s\n",value);
    
    
    return rep;

}
```

And now the main loop where i call this function after receiving the message :

```
char buffer[SIZE];
while(1){
          
            //Clean buffer
        memset(buffer,0,SIZE);
        FD_ZERO(&readfd);
        FD_SET(fd,&readfd);
        timeout.tv_sec=100;
        timeout.tv_usec=0;
            
        status=select(40,&readfd,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
            
        if(status==0){  
            printf("Cannot receive data from client\n");
            printf("\tTime Out\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        read_num=read(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        if(read_num<0) perror("Error in reading file descriptor\n");
        if(read_num>0){
                request=parse_request(buffer);  
                break;          
            
        }
        
    }
```

The main problem here is that strtok returns null in at value parameter despite that the message is AT+REG1=5 and it must show "5".

Comment: What is `buffer`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri It is a char array where i store there the message from the client

Comment: Writing `strtok("AT+REG1=5","=")` as an example is a bad example. The `strtok` function *modifies* the string, and literal strings can't be modified.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i wanted to show you what message am passing into strtok , i dont use this in my code .

Comment: @DavidRanieri Any idea why is this happening ? It must returns "5" but it returns null

Comment: It is unclear what delimitor is passed to the *second* call to `strtok`. In the example it is `"="` but further down it is `" "`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah i know that i had it with "=" but it shows me the same  outcome (null) and i changed it with the hope that it will run but still the same

Comment: The parse function does work (I've removed the irrelevant return value): https://onlinegdb.com/rJt1B5Cmu

Comment: I took your code, copied it, provided short `main` [and it works on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E6ej1W). There may be a problem in other parts of your code.

Comment: It's probably time to start using your debugger. The 60 minutes you need to invest to learn the basics of your debugger will quickly pay off.

Comment: @KamilCuk All am doing is opening a file :P ,  in the other part of the code

Comment: How are you printing it? Are you _sure_ you do not have dos line endings? What does `printf("%zu\n", strlen(value))` show? `if(read_num>0)` you do not check if what you read is zero terminated. You may read only part of the line, or only the first character. How do you know `buffer`  contains the string? Why is it zero terminated?

Comment: @KamilCuk  am getting Segmentation fault with printf("%zu\n", strlen(value))

Comment: *All am doing is opening a file*. Then it should be easy to show that and provide complete code. As it is, alot of time is being wasted with people guessing at missing code. See" [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Provide code with a fixed input and includes the exact code that verifies the result.

Comment: For example, you are not actually setting any of the fields in `rep`. Is that intentional and are you basing your conclusions on printing out those fields?

Comment: @KamilCuk bro thank you !!!!! PROBLEM SOLVED  i couldnt see that if(read_num)>0 was the the problem!!